Is the limit of quasi periodic function a almost periodic in compact open topology?
I'm doing some research on the topic of quasi periodic function and almost periodic function. I already know that the limit of quasi periodic function is an almost periodic function in the sense of uniformly convergence. But I'm confused about that if we change the way of convergence to compact open topology.
